# No-undef ignore pattern

Tags: eslint

Is there any way to exclude specific patterns from `no-undef` error. I tried `'no-undef': [2, { ignoreBuiltinGlobals: ['app'] }]` where `app` is my global variable defined by webpack.defineplugin. If I switch this rule off - no errors appear.

I also tried to insert `app: true` in `globals` section of `.eslintrc.js`

Or another way to get my variable `'def'` without errors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I understand that you want eslint to ignore the `app` global variable.

Did you try `/*global app */`?

More info [here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef)